# Conditional interceptor action upon request parameter in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I need to act conditionally in an HTTP Interceptor in Angular upon my **initial intention** before sending a request. Here is a simple abstract composition:

Exactly the same (URL, params, etc.) request made by **HttpClient**, two intentions:

1. Request which needs to show a loader (e.g. page change, initial load, etc.)

   `this.http.post(url, data, config = {**someCustomParam**: true});`
2. Request which **does not** show a loader (e.g. status check, ping, etc.)

   `this.http.post(url, data, config = {**someCustomParam**: false});`

Intercept the request result in some matter like that:

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }
  
  public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if(request.someCustomProperty) {
        **// Do somethnig on TRUE**
      } else {
        **// Do somethnig on FALSE**
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I cannot pass a custom parameter with my request and meet it back after response arrives. Here is what I have found so far:

1. One suggested passing any params in the config parameter of the http.get/http.post - does not work. It accepts only certain parameters.
2. Negotiate with the backend to pass-return something (like a header or a parameter) - breaks the separation of the front-end as we are becoming back-end dependant;
3. Use a decorator/extend HttpClient component, so I can pass my parameter - will work but I am searching for a native solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Detailed implementation using decorator Approach suggested by
Oleksandr. Might be useful for someone who lands here. https://medium.com/@abidhmuhsin/decorator-based-loader-for-angular-httpclient-f5b68853fb90 It was confusing at first but ended up exploring the topic and writing one for my own. This is the best way with least code changes. Thank You Oleksandr.

Comment: Wow, spectacular work! Thanks, @Abi.z

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I wrote a code that acts before executing the http request.

On the service of the loading component I added a function that prevents the next start order:

```js
    ignoreNextOrder(){
        this.ignore = true;
    }

    start() {
        if (this.ignore){
            this.ignore = false;
            return   
        }
        this.loadingSubject.next(LoadingType.LOADING);
    }
```

You have to manually call it before the requests you don't want to show loading animations so when the http call is made and the interceptor tries to start the loading animation, it's ignored.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question really, but I gave you a +1 because this is the solution I went with as it's exactly what I was looking this question up for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most correct way is to inject a service that should be responsible for making the decision if to do something or not by using a getter within that service.

In this example the decision if to modify the request and add an `Authorization` header is based upon the value of the getter `isAuthenticated` of the injected `AuthService`:

```
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.authService.isAuthenticated) {
            const authorizationHeader = this.authService.authorizationHeaderValue;
            const modifiedReq = req.clone({ 
                headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', authorizationHeader)
            });
            return next.handle(modifiedReq);
        }
        else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `AuthService`:

```
export class AuthService {

    private user: User | null;

    get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
    }

    get authorizationHeaderValue(): string {
        if (this.user)
            return `${this.user.token_type} ${this.user.access_token}`;
        else
            return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 approach would not be something recommended.

- For the first approach. If you are passing custom param and then you write some custom logic to avoid the loader display, imagine a case where 2 APIs are fired, one is should have loader and second should be ignore, now while handling the request you would be able to ignore the API which doesn't need loader but when the response comes, how will you distinguish if the api needs to be ignored or used to hided the loader. There are two solutions to this, one is you need to maintain a api point list, or else you need to put some logic in backend for sending a flag in the response.
- For overcoming the first problem you have the second solution. Here you need to make changes in the backend API. Which is something not recommended.

**Final Approach:**
What I would recommend you is to go for the third approach.

*You should create a decorator which should only be used when you need the loader to be displayed. That way it would be easier to understand for anyone else. Also the logic is not going to depend on backend.*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you adding your custom param as header to your request, anyway you can check it and delete from request in your interceptor. This would be the quickest solution.

...OR...

I used @LoaderTrigger decorator in one of my projects to launch loader, I did not use interceptor for that. All you need is to decorate a method or function which returns observable and implement LoaderManager. So here's what it looks like:

```
function LoaderTrigger(target, key, descriptor) {

if (descriptor === undefined) {
    descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);
}
const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

descriptor.value = function () {
    LoaderManager.onStarted();
    return originalMethod.apply(this, arguments)
        .map((value) => {
            LoaderManager.onLoaded();
            return value;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            LoaderManager.onLoaded();
            return Observable.throw(err);
        });
};

return descriptor;
}
```